# Estoy bajando un ejecutable a través de un subproceso en Python. Quiero añadir una barra de progreso pero no obtengo respuesta. ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso?

Tags: python-3.7

Este es mi código, aunque tengo bloqueadas algunas líneas de lo que he intentado. Agradeceria ayuda:

```
my_progress= ttk.Progressbar(ventana, orient=HORIZONTAL,length=200, mode='determinate')
my_progress.place(x= 1050, y=350)
           
p=subprocess.Popen(r"WHS.exe",shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = []
                                
my_progress["value"] +=20
my_label.config(text=my_progress["value"])
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! LAs mayusculas son porque estas gritando? si presionas ctrl+k sobre tu codigo, se arregla solo... y cual es el problema con ese codigo?

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822